# SQL Server Transactional log backup is larger than full backup

Tags: sql-server, transactions, backup, sql-server-2014, transaction-log

Transaction log backup is 450 mb but the full backup size is 10mb.

- BackupType: 2
- HasBulkLoggedData:0
- RecoveryModel:Full
- BackupTypeDescription :Transaction Log
- auto growth setting : By 512 MB, Limited to 2097152 MB
- correction, the size of the mdf file is 512 MB
- current LDF size is around 450 MB every 15 minutes.
- Full backup size is 11 MB

Comment: yes sql server 2014

Comment: I wish I could dupe this one across sites because this is a top frequent post on dba.stackexchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space I would start here as the answers are extremely thorough.

Comment: Also, [this post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/03/my-favorite-system-column-log_reuse_wait_desc/) from Brent Ozar and this related snippet may help: `SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases;`

Comment: question is about transaction log backup, not transaction log.

Comment: Perhaps there's a bunch of transactions (deletions) that are happening which doesn't increase the DB size but does for the transaction log. Also, how often are you taking log backups? And none of this is even 1 GB so....

Comment: taking backup every 15 minutes, and each time the size is around 500 MB

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, the transaction log backup contains activity, but the full backup just contains data.

For example, if you have an empty table, insert 100 rows, then delete all 100 rows, the table will still be empty. The full backup will just be the empty table, but the transaction log backup will record the 100 inserts and deletes.

Comment: but in my case i am not seeing any activity on database,

Comment: Can you use SQL Profiler or another monitoring tool to watch all database activity? For 500MB every 15 minutes there is definitely some activity.